# Python: loop over matrix to check for values in vector printing string + also row/column value

Tags: python, string, loops, matrix

I have this vector:

`possibleGrades = np.array([-3,0,2,4,7,10,12])`

And this matrix:

```
matrix=np.array([[7,7,4],[12,10,10],[-3,7,2],[10,8,12],[nan,7,nan],[7,7,10],[4.5,nan,2],[2,12,4]])
```

And then this code:

```
line, col = np.where(np.isin(matrixGrades, possibleGrades, invert=True))
print('Displaying incorrect or missing grades: \n')
[print(f'Incorrect or missing grade in row {line[i]} in column {col[i]}! Displaying the incorrect grade: {INSERT VALUE}.') for i in range(line.size)]
```

It should recognize 4.5, 8 and nan (no value in csv file) as incorrect values.

And in this line: `[print(f'Incorrect or missing grade in row {line[i]} in column {col[i]}! Displaying the incorrect grade: {INSERT VALUE}.') for i in range(line.size)]`

How can I get it to show the exact incorrect value in the row? I tried inserting `{matrix[i]}`, but does not help.

My output now: without "INSERT VALUE":

```
Displaying incorrect or missing grades: 

Incorrect or missing grade in row 3 in column 1! Displaying the incorrect grade: .
Incorrect or missing grade in row 4 in column 0! Displaying the incorrect grade: .
Incorrect or missing grade in row 4 in column 2! Displaying the incorrect grade: .
Incorrect or missing grade in row 6 in column 0! Displaying the incorrect grade: .
Incorrect or missing grade in row 6 in column 1! Displaying the incorrect grade: .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was almost right. With a slight modification you can get the desired output:

```
import numpy as np

possibleGrades = np.array([-3, 0, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12])
matrix = np.array([[7, 7, 4], [12, 10, 10], [-3, 7, 2], [10, 8, 12],
                   [np.nan, 7, np.nan],
                   [7, 7, 10], [4.5, np.nan, 2], [2, 12, 4]])

match = np.transpose(np.where(np.isin(matrix, possibleGrades, invert=True)))

print('Displaying incorrect or missing grades:')
for row, col in match:
    print(f"Incorrect or missing grade in row {row + 1} in"
          f"column {col + 1}! Displaying",
          f"the incorrect grade: {matrix[row, col]}.")
```

To get the value of the incorrect grade just evaluate in the `matrix` array with the previously obtained indexes. The sample output:

```
Displaying incorrect or missing grades:
Incorrect or missing grade in row 4 incolumn 2! Displaying the incorrect grade: 8.0.
Incorrect or missing grade in row 5 incolumn 1! Displaying the incorrect grade: nan.
Incorrect or missing grade in row 5 incolumn 3! Displaying the incorrect grade: nan.
Incorrect or missing grade in row 7 incolumn 1! Displaying the incorrect grade: 4.5.
Incorrect or missing grade in row 7 incolumn 2! Displaying the incorrect grade: nan.
```

Comment: You are truly a life saver! Thank you for your time and help!